# Add exception handling into Spring's batch ItemProcessor

Tags: spring-boot, exception, interface, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am using the Spring ItemProcessor<I, O> to perform batch jobs. The issue is I have a lot of boilerplate code and 20+ classes that implement the ItemProcessor<I, O>, each with different I and O.

My issue is I need to surround each process() implementation with a try {} catch () {} block. My first instinct is to create an abstract class with method overloading, but I'm not sure how I'd define each of the input and out in the ItemProcessor<I, O> in the child classes.

How can I implement exception handling to all of these ItemProcessor<I, O> implementations?

Example code:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ProfileProcessor implements ItemProcessor<List<ProfileData>,List<AcquirerProfile>>{

    @Override
    public List<Profile> process(List<Profile> profileDataList) {
        code...
        return profiles;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Example2 implements ItemProcessor<List<ExampleData>,List<Example>>{

    @Override
    public List<Example> process(List<Example> exampleList) {
        code...
        return examples;
    }
}
```

The goal is to surround each of these implementations in try catch blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register an [ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/repeat/exception/ExceptionHandler.html) in your simple of fault-tolerant step with `org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.AbstractTaskletStepBuilder#exceptionHandler`. This is the extension point that allows you to handle any exception that might happen while processing items.